# nested jquery $.each repeating iteration issue

Tags: jquery, object

hope you can help me with my issue, I'm iterating nested json using jquery $.each here's my sample code

```
function getList() {
 $.getJSON("src/list.json", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function( key, fax ) {
    const faxItem = this;
      displayOnDom.append(`<div id=faxPlan-${faxItem.id} class="pricing-table flex-item ${faxItem.recommended ? 'recommended' : ''}">
        <h3 class="pricing-title">${faxItem.title}</h3>
        <div class="price">${faxItem.price_per_month}<sup>/ month</sup></div>
        ${faxItem.button ? `<p class="rounded">${faxItem.button_text}</p>` : `<p class="norounded">${faxItem.button_text}</p>`}
        <div class="table-list"></div>
        `);
    $.each(fax.features, function( key, list ) {
      $('.table-list').append(`<p>${list.title}<span>${list.list}</span></p>`)
    })
  })   
});
```

}

I have a json file nested like this with multiple entries.

```
[{
"id": 1,
"title": "Pay-as-you-go",
"recommended": false,
"price_per_month": "$0.00",
"button": false,
"button_text":"For flexi-fax users, top up as you need with no lock-in contracts",
"icon": true,
"features": [{
        "title": "Send Credits Included",
        "list": "$0.30 Excess send credit charges "
    },
    {
        "title": "Received Credits Included",
        "list": "$0.30 Excess received credit charges "
    },
    {
        "title": "Free Fax Number",
        "list": ""
    }
],
"cta": {
    "label": "TRY FOR FREE",
    "link": "#"
}
```

},

My issue is that on the second $.each iteration, all of the features array are shown all together in the first iteration. It should be shown in their own iteration.

Hope my question's clear to you guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your second iteration code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick way to fix it is by adding `:last` to  `$('.table-list')`.

Currently the problem is that you are updating every `table-list`.

Solution 1 could be: `$('.table-list:last')`

**Solution 1**

```js
var displayOnDom = $(".test");

var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Pay-as-you-go",
    "recommended": false,
    "price_per_month": "$0.00",
    "button": false,
    "button_text": "For flexi-fax users, top up as you need with no lock-in contracts",
    "icon": true,
    "features": [{
        "title": "Send Credits Included",
        "list": "$0.30 Excess send credit charges "
      },
      {
        "title": "Received Credits Included",
        "list": "$0.30 Excess received credit charges "
      },
      {
        "title": "Free Fax Number",
        "list": ""
      }
    ],
    "cta": {
      "label": "TRY FOR FREE",
      "link": "#"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Pay-as-you-go",
    "recommended": false,
    "price_per_month": "$0.00",
    "button": false,
    "button_text": "For flexi-fax users, top up as you need with no lock-in contracts",
    "icon": true,
    "features": [{
        "title": "Send Credits Included",
        "list": "$0.30 Excess send credit charges "
      },
      {
        "title": "Received Credits Included",
        "list": "$0.30 Excess received credit charges "
      },
      {
        "title": "Free Fax Number",
        "list": ""
      }
    ],
    "cta": {
      "label": "TRY FOR FREE",
      "link": "#"
    }
  }
]

$.each(data, function(key, fax) {
  const faxItem = this;
  displayOnDom.append(`<div id=faxPlan-${faxItem.id} class="pricing-table flex-item ${faxItem.recommended ? 'recommended' : ''}">
        <h3 class="pricing-title">${faxItem.title}</h3>
        <div class="price">${faxItem.price_per_month}<sup>/ month</sup></div>
        ${faxItem.button ? `<p class="rounded">${faxItem.button_text}</p>` : `<p class="norounded">${faxItem.button_text}</p>`}
        <div class="table-list"></div>
        `);
  $.each(fax.features, function(key, list) {
    $('.table-list:last').append(`<p>${list.title}<span>${list.list}</span></p>`)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

**Solution 2**

```
$.each(data, function(key, fax) {
  const faxItem = this;
  var t = $(`<div id=faxPlan-${faxItem.id} class="pricing-table flex-item ${faxItem.recommended ? 'recommended' : ''}">
        <h3 class="pricing-title">${faxItem.title}</h3>
        <div class="price">${faxItem.price_per_month}<sup>/ month</sup></div>
        ${faxItem.button ? `<p class="rounded">${faxItem.button_text}</p>` : `<p class="norounded">${faxItem.button_text}</p>`}
        <div class="table-list"></div>
        `);
  $.each(fax.features, function(key, list) {
    $(t).find('.table-list').append(`<p>${list.title}<span>${list.list}</span></p>`)
  })
  displayOnDom.append(t);
})
```

```js
var displayOnDom = $(".test");

var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Pay-as-you-go",
    "recommended": false,
    "price_per_month": "$0.00",
    "button": false,
    "button_text": "For flexi-fax users, top up as you need with no lock-in contracts",
    "icon": true,
    "features": [{
        "title": "Send Credits Included",
        "list": "$0.30 Excess send credit charges "
      },
      {
        "title": "Received Credits Included",
        "list": "$0.30 Excess received credit charges "
      },
      {
        "title": "Free Fax Number",
        "list": ""
      }
    ],
    "cta": {
      "label": "TRY FOR FREE",
      "link": "#"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Pay-as-you-go",
    "recommended": false,
    "price_per_month": "$0.00",
    "button": false,
    "button_text": "For flexi-fax users, top up as you need with no lock-in contracts",
    "icon": true,
    "features": [{
        "title": "Send Credits Included",
        "list": "$0.30 Excess send credit charges "
      },
      {
        "title": "Received Credits Included",
        "list": "$0.30 Excess received credit charges "
      },
      {
        "title": "Free Fax Number",
        "list": ""
      }
    ],
    "cta": {
      "label": "TRY FOR FREE",
      "link": "#"
    }
  }
]

$.each(data, function(key, fax) {
  const faxItem = this;
  var t = $(`<div id=faxPlan-${faxItem.id} class="pricing-table flex-item ${faxItem.recommended ? 'recommended' : ''}">
        <h3 class="pricing-title">${faxItem.title}</h3>
        <div class="price">${faxItem.price_per_month}<sup>/ month</sup></div>
        ${faxItem.button ? `<p class="rounded">${faxItem.button_text}</p>` : `<p class="norounded">${faxItem.button_text}</p>`}
        <div class="table-list"></div>
        `);
  $.each(fax.features, function(key, list) {
    $(t).find('.table-list').append(`<p>${list.title}<span>${list.list}</span></p>`)
  })
  displayOnDom.append(t);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for pointing out my issue! Solution 2 works for me as I needed to add more dom elements after the second $.each.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the newly created `.table-list` using `.appendTo` (rather than `.append`) so that it can be appended to:

```
function getList() {
 $.getJSON("src/list.json", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function( key, fax ) {
      const faxItem = this;
      displayOnDom.append(`<div id=faxPlan-${faxItem.id} class="pricing-table flex-item ${faxItem.recommended ? 'recommended' : ''}">
        <h3 class="pricing-title">${faxItem.title}</h3>
        <div class="price">${faxItem.price_per_month}<sup>/ month</sup></div>
        ${faxItem.button ? `<p class="rounded">${faxItem.button_text}</p>` : `<p class="norounded">${faxItem.button_text}</p>`}
        `);


      var tablelist = $('<div class="table-list"></div>').appendTo(displayOnDom);

      $.each(fax.features, function( key, list ) {
        tablelist.append(`<p>${list.title}<span>${list.list}</span></p>`)
      })
   })   
 });
}
```